# Hash Tables: Ransom Note - Hacker Rank in Swift Timed Out

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3, hashmap

My code is alright but keeping getting time out on some test cases, any tips to improve this? My guess is the indexOf function taking too long.

```
func checkMagazine(magazine: [String], note: [String]) -> Void {
var mutableMag = magazine
if note.count > mutableMag.count {
    print("No")
    return
}
for word in note {
    if let index = mutableMag.index(of: word) {
        mutableMag.remove(at: index)
    } else {
        print("No")
        return
    }
}
print("Yes") }
```

Please find the challenge in this link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem

Comment: You already got a good answer, but note that this would be also a good question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. They have dedicated tags “programming-challenge” and “time-limit-exceeded” for such problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution that passes all tests is using `NSCountedSet` for storing the words in the note and magazine and comparing the count of each word in `note` to the count of that word in `magazine` and if any of them is lower in `magazine`, making an early return and printing `No`.

I'd also suggest changing the function signature to return a `Bool` value even though the function prototype generated by hacker rank returns `Void`. It's better to make `checkMagazine` a pure function and not doing any I/O operations in it.

```
func checkMagazine(magazine: [String], note: [String]) -> Bool {
    let magazineWords = NSCountedSet(array: magazine)
    let noteWords = NSCountedSet(array: note)
    for noteWord in noteWords {
        if magazineWords.count(for: noteWord) < noteWords.count(for: noteWord) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Then you just need to change the end of the generated code to the following:

```
let magazineWorks = checkMagazine(magazine: magazine, note: note)
if magazineWorks {
    print("Yes")
} else {
    print("No")
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, thank you. One question, the problem of my code is the indexOf function?

Comment: @ArildoJunior essentially yes. The time compexity of `Array.index(of:)` is linear (`O(n)`) and since you call `index(of:)` in a loop for all elements of the array, the time complexity of your algorithm is quadratic (`O(n^2)`). On the other hand, `NSCountedSet.count(for: )` has constant time complexity (`O(1)`), so the algorithm in my answer has linear time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
func checkMagazine(magazine: [String], note: [String]) -> Void {
    var notesDictionary : [String : Int] = [:]
    var magazineDictionary : [String : Int] = [:]

    var canMakeRansom = true

    for n in note {
        var count = notesDictionary[n] ?? 0
        count += 1
        notesDictionary[n] = count
    }

    for n in magazine {
        var count = magazineDictionary[n] ?? 0
        count += 1
        magazineDictionary[n] = count
    }

    for note in notesDictionary {
        if note.value > magazineDictionary[note.key] ?? 0 {
            canMakeRansom = false
        }
    }
    print(canMakeRansom ? "Yes" : "No")
}
```

This is another way to solve this.
I think this does what NSCountedSet does by itself somehow.